# My app is not in ranking in App Store for added keywords

Tags: ios-appstore

I launched my app on the App Store a couple days ago. It is not showing in the ranking for the added keywords.

Is there a reason for that?

My app name contains **to do list** words.

[image]

Comment: Have a look at [meta] for why we’re not customer support for Apple and also [help] on subjective questions. This seems a little too subjective since the actual app volumes that make a rating will change day by day.

Answer (score 2):

App Store rankings for apps under various categories is based on algorithms employed in the Apple's servers. How the ranking process works is not public knowledge.

So, there is **no** definitive answer as to why your app is not there in the ranking (maybe there's a minimum threshold to compete for ranking).

Additionally, why or how Apple does something doesn't fall under the purview of what's discussed on this site. It is generally considered off-topic. Please have a look at these links:

- http://meta.apple.stackexchange.com/questions/2508/why-were-not-customer-support-for-company-x-or-product-y
- https://apple.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic
- https://apple.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask